# Как перехватить любую ошибку в приложении на golang и выполнить перезагрузку самой программы?

Tags: golang

Как перехватить любую ошибку в приложении на  golang и выполнить перезагрузку самой программы ?
Бывает, что возникают ошибки, которые я не обработал и что б приложение вообще не стало и работало потом корректно, нужно как-то перезапустится, только как бинарник запустит сам себя?  может какой-то .bat файл написать или как это вообще делается?

Comment: Если не использовать горутины, то можно перезапускать recoverom. Вот [пример](http://play.golang.org/p/YLckKwcs21). Но, желательно, провести тестирование - вероятно переполнение стека при очень многих перезапусках (не знаю как go оптимизирует код, может и нет). Иначе проще батник - это да (или иную обёртку).

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо бросать паник везде где не сделана обработка ошибки, а потом отловить его и рестартнуть при помощи systemd

Answer (score 0):

Я использую простенькую програмку которая проверяет порты открытые(из конфигурационного JSON'а если они заняты - все отлично, если освободились берет(опять же из конфигурации) путь к файлу и запускает его через:

```
cmd := exec.Command("path/to/file.exe")
```

И во всех тонких местах стоят:

```
func myFunc(){
    defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                err := fmt.Errorf("%v", r)
                helpers.DebugErrHandler("Error: ", err)
                return
            }
        }()
}
```